# Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined even after defining bind(this.submit)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I've been working on react js and want to `setState` for response from firebase.
So when I'm trying to set value for state, it returns the error ,

> Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

My code.

```
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {email:'',
                    uid:'',
                    password :'',
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
        this.signInWithGoogle = this.signInWithGoogle.bind(this)
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.id] : event.target.value
        })
        console.log(this.state.email)
        console.log(this.state.password)
      }
      handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(function(result)  {
            console.log(result.user.uid)
            this.setState({ [uid]: [result.user.uid] });
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error.code)
            console.log(error.message)
            alert(error.message)
           })
      }
```

I do have a form to give inputs . 
Can somebody help me on this .

Comment: Error shows up inside handleChange or handleSubmit?

Comment: You need to make callback of 'signInWithEmailAndPassword( () => {})' as arrow function. then only parent/class 'this' context will be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your handleSubmit function like this

```
      handleSubmit(e) {
       e.preventDefault()
       firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, 
       this.state.password).then((result) => {
         console.log(result.user.uid)
         this.setState({ uid: result.user.uid });
       }).catch(function(error) {
         console.log(error.code)
         console.log(error.message)
         alert(error.message)
       })
     }
```

this scope is only available inside the fat arrow function () => {}, so I have just updated your function

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(function(result)  {
```

to

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((result) =>  {
```

Comment: Now it directly skips to catch(error) statement . What's wrong?

Comment: add this line at the starting of your function
const {uid, email, password} = this.state;

Comment: yeah because uid is a state variable sorry i did not noticed it, so it should be this.setState({ uid : result.user.uid })

Answer (score 1):

You can either use arrow function or store `this` in another variable.

**Method 1:**

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((result) => {
        console.log(result.user.uid)
        this.setState({ [uid]: [result.user.uid] });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error.code)
        console.log(error.message)
        alert(error.message)
    })
}
```

**Method 2**

```
 handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let _this = this;
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(function(result)  {
        console.log(result.user.uid)
        _this.setState({ [uid]: [result.user.uid] });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error.code)
        console.log(error.message)
        alert(error.message)
    })
}
```

Comment: I changed the code as per the first method . Now it shows `uid is not defined` . which comes from `error` function . I think it skips the result function .

Answer (score 1):

You need to write const `that = this;` as a first line in your handleSubmit method and use `that` instead of `this` in your function.

Answer (score 1):

in the second setState method inside firebase `signInWithEmailAndPassword` you are using anonymous function which has it's own `this` scope. so the `this.setState` will take the reference inside the function itself and not the class `this`.
In order to make sure your setState gets the lexical `this` of the class , you would have to use arrow function :

```
  firebase
   .auth()
   .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
   .then((result) => { // arrow function used
        console.log(result.user.uid)
        this.setState({ [uid]: [result.user.uid] });
   })
```

You can also use @Sukrut Bam  answer explanation as one of your methodology

Comment: Sure . Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Actual Answer was provided to the query. I want to say that you can use arrow function syntax to bind functions automatically.

e.g.

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault()
       firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, 
       this.state.password).then((result) => {
         console.log(result.user.uid)
         this.setState({ uid: result.user.uid });
       }).catch(function(error) {
         console.log(error.code)
         console.log(error.message)
         alert(error.message)
       })
     }
```

So you would not have to write

```
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your handleSubmit() function as followed :

```
handleSubmit(e) {
       e.preventDefault()
       firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, 
       this.state.password).then((result) => {
         console.log(result.user.uid)
         this.setState({ uid: result.user.uid });
       }).catch(function(error) {
         console.log(error.code)
         console.log(error.message)
         alert(error.message)
       })
     }
```